# Typos in Gentle's Matrix Algebra?

Tags: matrices

In Gentle's (2007, p.180) *Matrix Algebra*, he writes [image]

It seems to me that this requires $u$ to be orthonormal (i.e. unit length), not just orthogonal to $v$ as hypothesized in the text, because $u^Tu=1$ only in that circumstance.

Second, in the last sentence, he says $H$ reflects $x$ across $u$, but doesn't it reflect $x$ across $v$ along $u$? If not why not?

Comment: http://mason.gmu.edu/~jgentle/books/matbk/materrata.htm

Comment: two relevant bits are Page 180, line 5:
"orthogonal" should be "orthonormal"
(Thanks again to Clark Fitzgerald!)
Page 180, lines 5 and 15:
"u" should be "v"; that is, the reflection is about v
(Thanks to Eric Arora!)